# Does Windows 7 have a repair installation (like XP had), i.e. booting to the repair install, and where you don't lose data?

Tags: windows-7

Does Windows 7 have a repair installation (like XP had)  - i.e. booting to the repair install, and where you don't lose data?

I have heard that it doesn't.

Added-
To clarify.  Windows XP had 2 repair options. Repair from recovery console. And after clicking "install" you get another repair option that some would call a  ["Repair Installation"](http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm) which installs the main windows files over itself, without creating a new windows installation or wiping your existing one. It preserves program files and the user files (that are in "c:\documents and settings").
It is that which I am referring to by "Repair Installation" A repair that involves an installation process. In XP it was pretty much a fix all kind of solution for any windows issue, fixed any BSOD.

Comment: @Ramhound see my update.  I'm aware that Windows 7 has those repair options. But not the so-called 'repair installation'/'reoair that involves installation' type that XP had.

Comment: @Ramhound Your bleepingcomputer link http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/   makes my point very well. Notice that in your link, it's an example where his startup repair or his system restore wasn't fixing the problem, and he tried to fix things in his registry. That is my point (though when I had an issue, I could get into safe mode and run regedit no need to load any hive) but you can run a startup repair or system restore and still not get in, leaving windows still corrupt. Windows XP repair installation always fixe a corrupt windows.

Comment: @Ramhound You don't seem to understand what i'm saying. The XP recovery console was very limited I agree. But XP has an option you seem to be completely unaware of. I am not referring to the recovery console. Try reading my post again, and my answer where it relates to XP. Specifically the 6th paragraph of my answer, which starts "With XP you booted off the CD,"  And read my question where I wrote "Added" and I mentioned that option, before your latest comment. And  look at that link in my question that relates to what i'm saying(an option you seem to be unfamiliar with).

Comment: @Ramhound Furthermore, in the link I gave in my question, you see specifically that i'm not talking about the recovery console. Here is a quote from the link "Press Enter to start the Windows Setup. 
To Repair Install, press ENTER

 To setup Windows XP now and Repair Install , press ENTER. Do Not choose 'To repair a Windows XP installation using the Recovery Console, press  R', (you Do Not want to load Recovery Console). I repeat, Do Not choose 'To repair a Windows XP installation using the Recovery Console, press  R'. " <-- Perhaps you didn't see that or understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14553/discussion-between-barlop-and-ramhound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, it doesn't. You get an error message with the closest thing "upgrade" if you try from booting or even from safe mode.

Windows 7 does have some recovery options.. that XP didn't have. Besides a command prompt(better than the XP recovery console), that even recognizes USB. It has system restore as an option, and startup repair as an option. None of these are like the windows xp repair installation though.. Startup repair is quick but not as powerful as an installation process that overwrites the main windows files getting you into windows.

I've had a situation where (if I recall), Windows 7's startup repair couldn't fix it(it didn't detect a problem, perhaps because the BSOD occurred quite late, like near login time). And certainly the system restore wasn't fixing it. Had there been a repair installation, that might've fixed it.

There is an "upgrade" option which seems like it does what XP's repair installation did but it won't run from booting, and it won't run from safe mode either! (And since it's called upgrade I suppose it wasn't designed for repairing windows). And it requires that you be able to boot into normal mode and that it be run from there

I'll update with some screenshots.

With XP you booted off the CD, it said Install or Repair, if you chose repair at that stage it was repair from recovery console. So you could do that but the repair installation was different. You can click install and then repair and that was a repair installation.

In Windows 7, it offers repair and install, the repair there is a cmd prompt more than the xp recovery console but obviously not a repair installation. If you choose install, it offers custom and upgrade. Custom puts any other windows installation into windows.old (and it looks like you might lose program files with it and perhaps other things).   "Upgrade"   is the other of the two options, which thus far i've never found/had a use for. It's certainly not a repair installation!

When trying to boot off the DVD/USB

[image]

When trying to run from Safe Mode (i.e. run E:\setup.exe - if E is the USB/DVD drive with the windows setup on it).

[image]

When running from Normal mode,  the "upgrade" option works, and might be as good as xp's repair installation. But if you're not able to get into normal mode, you won't be able to run it.

For the sake of completeness, here is a pic of a post where I thought there was a repair installation but was corrected well by kinokijuf.

[image]

The point is made in the instructions in this tutorial on it too

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

> You can only do a repair install from within Windows 7.
>
> You cannot do a repair install at boot or in Safe Mode.
>
> You must be logged into Windows 7 in a administrator account to be able to do a repair install.

**Added**

A repair installation is also missing from Windows 10 in exactly the same way. I don't know about Vista. But they must have removed it from windows post XP.

If you boot a win10, it asks you about what language you want to use, you click next, you click 'repair', the options are limited, no repair installation like XP had. And if you boot win10 and click next(when it asks you what language), and next(not clicking repair), then it shows you the options of custom and upgrade.

So in not just win7, but win10,  they have the options 'custom' and 'upgrade', and 'upgrade' only works from within windows so only works if you can boot in.  'upgrade' won't work from a WinPE i.e. e.g. the 'upgrade' option won't work from a windows installation bootable usb.

As an example of the difference.  In WinXP if you were to remove the windows directory or the windows\system32 directory, or whatever, then you could do a repair installation, off USB, and it'd fix it. You can't do that with Win7 or Win10.

The design is, Windows 7 added a "startup repair" and then made the repair installation not need to run from boot. So you'd run the startup repair then once/if that's sorted, you'd run the win7 repair installation. An issue with that though is there's no guarantee that the startup repair will work, whereas the WinXP repair would always work (provided the windows installation media isn't corrupted and provided the hardware is ok!)

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. Please back this up with some evidence with sources.

Comment: @CharlieRB my screenshots. And the fact that you and nobody else can give a source showing Windows 7 doing a "repair installation" as in, http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm  As in, a repair process that involves installing windows. (not creating a new windows installation or totally wiping or moving/renaming one).

Comment: I see what you are saying. Windows 7 does thing more autonomously than XP, and things are not called the same. Here are the recovery options information - [What are the system recovery options in Windows?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7). I think you may be running into issues with an OEM DVD, which has restrictions compared to a retail DVD. Here is some info about [How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html). Good luck.

Comment: @CharlieRB That link you gave http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html  makes my point.  Notice in that link you gave they say to click the UPGRADE option. That is what I wrote in my answer is the closest thing to the (let's call it) Repair via installation that you had in XP. The repair installation.  Now look what your own link says. It says to log in first. And what if you can't log in? Well, my post shows -with screenshots- that if you can't log in in normal mode, you can't run it. And it won't even run from safe mode.

Comment: OK. I get your point, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist just because you can't use it. I only added that link with hopes it might help you get past where you are stuck. Some installations are too far gone for it to work and require a clean install. Good luck.

Comment: @CharlieRB What are you talking about saying I can't use it and it might exist. If you are talking about a recovery like in XP that you can boot from even when the comp is "so far gone" that you can't get in in normal mode, then you can't "use it" either, nobody can IF you/me/they can't boot up into normal mode. Such a feature doesn't exist. But Did in XP and I and perhaps you, used it many times. And I don't know where you read that I was stuck. I asked a question and I answered it, and you say you get the point(I don't know exactly what point you get but anyway)

Comment: maybe yes that you don't lose data, but no, it won't run from booting.

Comment: and I think I finally understand the logic of it.. it's effectively similar to what XP offered. It just added a startup repair and then made the repair installation not need to run from boot. So you'd run the startup repair then once/if that's sorted, you'd run the win7 repair installation